# Google's text-to-speech fails to connect

Tags: python, gtts

I am getting an error
this is the code i wrote

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from gtts import gTTS
import os
import time
import playsound



def speak(text):
    tts = gTTS(text=text, lang="en")
    filename = "voice.mp3"
    tts.save(filename)
    playsound.playsound(filename)
speak("hello Aneeqa")
```

**this is the error**

> File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gtts\tts.py", line 281, in stream
> raise gTTSError(tts=self)
> gtts.tts.gTTSError: Failed to connect. Probable cause: Unknown

> Process finished with exit code 1